# How to customize not cms components in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a task to override some general functionality in Spartacus core (angular component), which is used in other OTTB components (like CMS and not CMS).

The example is `cx-generic-link`.

But I faced with problem that the only way of customizing OOTB components are if they are cms Components.

**Question**: Is there any way to customize `cx-generic-link` (for instance display name "*Maks*" everywhere), so that all other Spartacus components (which I am using as a library) use my `cx-generic-link`, but not a OOTB `cx-generic-link`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than CSS customisation there's currently no concept for this in Spartacus nor in Angular. We're working on a more generic concept to customise lower level components, but it's likely not going to make it in 2.0. It's still a stretch for 2.0 though, but with the various priorities we have, this is likely moving to a later release.